# Parse all bytearray values in a JSON in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I have a complex object that has some properties of `bytearray` type and when I try to convert it to JSON it throws this error:

> TypeError: Object of type bytearray is not JSON serializable.

I can make a method hardcoding the properties that I know that are `bytearray` type and then do this:

> bytes(key.key_value).decode("utf-8")

The problem is that I have lots of possible cases and I'd like to make a generic method that allows me to parse all `bytearray` properties of a JSON to `string`.
I tried to make my own `json.JSONEncoder` implementation but it didn't work. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically this is just not supported in json.  How will you tell the difference between bytearrays and strings when loading data?

Comment: @wim I don't care since I only want to show the decoded value in a console

Comment: OK, so you don't need to load the json in again?  You just want the bytearray to look like a string in the output?

Comment: @wim Yes! That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Decide on the encoding and error handling behaviour that you want to use for decoding bytearrays to strings, and then:

```
import json

class FunkyJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, bytearray):
            return obj.decode("utf-8", errors="replace")
        else:
            return super().default(obj)
```

Usage example:

```
>>> dumps = FunkyJSONEncoder().encode
>>> dumps({'k': bytearray(b'potato')})
'{"k": "potato"}'
```

Comment: It didn't work: TypeError: Object of type MyType is not JSON serializable. However, I made it work with another solution I came up with. Thanks anyway!